# Rabbit mq start up error - application_start_failure

Tags: erlang, runtime-error, rabbitmq, startup

I am trying to set up a HA rabbit mq cluster and I am following the instruction in https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

The first rabbit mq server is fine, whereas in the second and third rabbitmq servers I am getting the below error,

```
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erl
```

I have double check `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` on all three servers have the same value. Stuck with this error, any help on this is appreciated

Comment: By the way, the error message appears as truncated but it is not - I triple checked it in erl_crash.dump as well, that is the complete error message

Comment: The .erlang.cookie usually resides in the home directory of the user that is running rabbitmq. Can you move the cookie to ~/ and try if they start up

Comment: Tried that too, and doesn't work. Having the same issue

Comment: Can you please post the output of netstat -an | grep 5672 (this has to be run on the hosts that the node cannot start). I'm trying to see if some other application is using that port.

Comment: When I do a netstat -an | grep 5672 I see nothing

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is too late but I run into this same issue. Here how I solved it:

1. Run `rabbitmqctl status` (as root or use sudo). It gave me some error messages. One of them was:

> {error_logger,{{2016,9,20},{12,4,22}},"Cookie file
>   /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[]}

2. Then run  `ls -l /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`. It returns to me this:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 20 Set 25  2014 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

3. Then change the permissions using `chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`

I think other users may have to change the ownership too. It was not my case tough.